# pulling events from MySQL table by start and end date, retaining currently active events

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a MySQL table that contains event data. The important columns are from_date and to_date. Both contain epoch timestamps to represent when the events starts, and ends.

I query the table to pull events that fall within a specified date range using:

```
from_date >= $from_date AND to_date <= $to_date
```

This is all good, but my problem now is that events that started before the from_date, but match the to_date rule is not being selected, ie the event started before the from_date but are still active... Same goes for events that match the from_date rule but pass the to_date. I need to see "active" events in the result also.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your check to:

```
`from_data` BETWEEN $from AND $to OR `to_date` BETWEEN $from AND $to
```

In English: event starts or ends between `$from` and `$to`.

If your `$from` and `$to` are: `10:00` and `11:00`. Then this query will give you:

```
9:00 9:50 (no)
9:00 12:00 (yes)
9:00 10:10 (yes)
10:20 10:30 (yes)
10:50 11:10 (yes)
11:20 12:00 (no)
```

Comment: event that goes from 9:00 - 12:00 will not show up as an active event. (clarified)

Comment: Updated, had to flip the variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you we search for all events that start before the $to_date and end after the $from_date, it should pull what you are looking for.

`from_date <= $to_date AND to_date >= $from_date`

If your $from and $to are: 10:00 and 11:00. Then this query will give you:

- 9:00 9:50 (no because 9:50 < 10)
- 9:00 10:10 (yes)
- 10:20 10:30 (yes)
- 10:50 11:10 (yes)
- 11:20 12:00 (no because 11:20 > 11:00)
- **9:00 12:00 (yes because 9 is < 11 and 12 > 10)**

Comment: I had tried approach before and it didn't give the result expected, and guess what, just tried it again and its working as expected...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you keep track of active events somehow to maybe you can try this:

```
  (from_date >= $from_date AND to_date <= $to_date) OR active = 1
```

**This is an idea not copy/paste code**

Comment: no, the "active" is determined by the fact that timestamps imply that the event is active. the issue is that the from_date > fromDate AND to_date < toDate is too strict and ignoring events that fall outside one direction or the other... To add an active=1 column is going to require a cron job - there must be a method to handle this in the query..